# Retrieve certain object from an array and act upon retrieval

Tags: jquery, arrays

I hadn't received a concrete answer from my previous thread: [Retrieve "id" from array in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774779/retrieve-id-from-array-in-jquery)

So I'll try to explain  in more detail and show what I did.

I'm working on a small game and I have several obstacles in an array like so:

```
obstacles = [ { id: '#car' }, { id: '#house' }, { id: '#door' }, ];
```

In the second part of my code, I have:

**JQuery:**

```
 $('#alert').hide();
 for (index in obstacles) {

        object = $(obstacles[index]["id"]);


    obj_left = object.position().left + parseInt(object.css("margin-left"));
    obj_top = object.position().top + parseInt(object.css("margin-top"));



      if ((((posX > (obj_left - me.width() / 2)) && 
      (posX < (obj_left + object.width() + me.width() / 2)))) && 
     (posY > (obj_top - me.height() / 2)) && 
     (posY < (obj_top + object.height() + me.height() / 2))) {


            // Cannot walk 
            return false;
        }
    // it's starts to get ugly here.
    if (object == '#car') {
    $('#character').hide();  
    }
    if (object == '#door') {
    $('#noenter-alert').show();
    }
    }
    // Can walk again
    return true && $('#character[).show(), $('#noenter-alert').hide();   
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="alert">//...</div>
<div id="character"></div>
<div class="door" id="door"></div>
<div class="house" id="house"></div>
<div class="car" id="car"></div>
```

I tested it out and it worked great. But instead of displaying an alert for every obstacle, I just want to retrieve the value of a certain obstacle (i.e: if the player hits a car, hide the player or if the player hits a door output "you may not enter!").

Hope I've been straightforward and have provided a fair amount of code.

And Here's the link to the tutorial I followed: http://blog.oscarliang.net/pokemon-online-game-theme-tutorial/

Thanks! I apologize for the repost but I hope that someone can fix this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert should be in the if condition

```
if ((((posX > (obj_left - me.width() / 2)) && (posX < (obj_left + object.width() + me.width() / 2)))) && (posY > (obj_top - me.height() / 2)) && (posY < (obj_top + object.height() + me.height() / 2))) {
 //Here You need to put the alert
        alert(object+'is here')
        return false;
    }
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/symonsarwar/6Ffxk/22/